# Did Jinliang Wang solve the P versus NP problem?

Tags: p-vs-np

Recently, I saw a paper on the Internet [1]. Did the author of this paper, Jinliang Wang, solve the P versus NP problem?

**Reference**

[1] Wang, J. L. (2018) Fast Algorithm for the Travelling Salesman Problem and the Proof of P = NP. *Applied Mathematics*, 9, 1351-1359. doi: 10.4236/am.2018.912088.

Comment: The URL of this paper is "https://doi.org/10.4236/am.2018.912088".

Comment: The list of papers* from this prolific researcher shows that he also proved the Riemann hypothesis in 2019 and in 2021. Alas, the two papers were retracted...

* https://www.scirp.org/journal/articles.aspx?searchcode=Jinliang++Wang&searchfield=authors&page=1

Comment: @Pamphile I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the pruning in the paper doesn’t work. For example, consider a graph on four nodes where two nodes have distance 1 while the other two have distance 101, with all other edges having distance 100. The most efficient route takes the longest edge, while avoiding it takes an extra distance of 98.

In general  be very suspicious of any claimed proof or disproof of P = NP.

Comment: “In general be very suspicious of any claimed proof or disproof of P = NP.”  Any proof accepted by the community — even anything that looks like it has a serious chance of being correct — will receive truly massive publicity.  If a claimed proof has languished for four years without much attention, that means that researchers in the field don’t think it’s worth taking seriously.

Comment: @PLL I understand. Thank you.